# Add Serialize attribute to type from third-party lib

Tags: serialization, attributes, rust

I'm trying to add serialization functionality to one of my structs in Rust.
It's an event for a calendar and looks like this:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Encodable, Decodable)]
pub struct Event {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub desc: String,
    pub location: String,
    pub start: DateTime<Local>,
    pub end: DateTime<Local>,
}
```

The struct uses two different types from third-parties, the `Uuid` is from https://github.com/rust-lang/uuid and the `DateTime` from https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono.

If I try to build the project the compiler complains that `encode` was not found for `Uuid` and `DateTime`, which is because they both do not derive `Encodable` and `Decodeable`, from the `serialize` crate.

So the questions are:
Is there a way to add derives to third-party structs without touching the code of the libs itself? If not, what is the best way to add serialization functionality in a situation like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to use `Encodable` and `Decodable`; you want to use `RustcEncodable` and `RustcDecodable` from the [`rustc-serialize`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-serialize) crate.

Secondly, you can't.  If you didn't write the type in question *or* the trait in question, you just can't: this is a *deliberate guarantee* on the part of the compiler. (See also "coherence".)

There are two things you can do in this situation:

1. **Implement the traits manually.**  Sometimes, `derive` doesn't work, so you have to write the trait implementation by hand.  In this case, it would give you the opportunity to just manually implement encoding/decoding for the unsupported types directly.
2. **Wrap the unsupported types.**  This means doing something like `struct UuidWrap(pub Uuid);`.  This gives you a new type that *you* wrote, which means you can... well, do #1, but do it for a smaller amount of code.  Of course, *now* you have to wrap and unwrap the UUID, which is a *bit* of a pain.

Comment: What if he uses `serde`? Doesn't `serde` uses `Encodable`/`Decodable`?

Comment: From the docs on the repo, no, it uses different traits.  Also, they specifically mention the `serialize` crate.  Anyway, if they *are* using Serde, they should say so, or the answer won't be useful. :)

Comment: What's the difference between `serialize` and `rustc-serialize`?

Comment: @0kp One is internal to the compiler and shouldn't be used by anyone else, the other is on crates.io and *can* be used by others.  For reasons which I'm sure made sense at the time, they are `serialize` and `rustc-serialize` *in that order*.  No, really.  Yes, I know how that looks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I was looking for the solution for same issue. Chrono has enabled the rustc-serialize support. You have to enable it by adding dependecy as follows.

```
[dependencies.chrone]
version = "*"
features = ["rustc-serialize"]
```

I got to know about this from the answer given by [ker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103681/ker) to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311559/json-serialization-for-rust-chrono). Hope it will helpful to you.