# Json Serialization feature of chrono crate

Tags: serialization, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use DateTime from rust-chrono crate to my own trait.

```
#[derive(Debug, RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
pub struct Accomplishment {
  name: String,
  accomplishment_type: String,
  date: DateTime<UTC>
}
```

When I try to compile this it complains that

```
src/lib.rs:11:33: 11:47 error: the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable` is not implemented for the type `chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::UTC>` [E0277]
src/lib.rs:11 #[derive(Debug, RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
```

When I checked the [github repo of chrono](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono) it had the rustc_serialize support implemented. But it is as a feature. In [commit log](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono/commit/b5281af9f3014c4ef50212d282bca6de6d50a22c) it has

```
cargo test -v --features rustc-serialize
```

I'm not sure how to have this feature for my project. Can someone help me on how to use chrono with rustc-serialize?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793710/add-serialize-attribute-to-type-from-third-party-lib) regarding this. But what I wanted is to use the serialization support available in chrono in my project without implementing a wrapper trait.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the feature to your dependency in the `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies.chrono]
version = "*"
features = ["rustc-serialize"]
```

The relevant Documentation can be found [here](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[features]-section)