# How can I copy the fields of another structure?

Tags: rust

Is there any crate or functionality that allows me to copy the fields from another structure?

**Crate A**

```
struct Product {
    name: String,
    sku: String,
    amount: i32,
}
```

**Crate B**

```rust
#[derive(copy_fields_from = "a::Product", InputObject)]
struct ProductApi {}
```

I have to expose several objects from another crate in an API that uses
"`#[derive(InputObject)]`". For that, I have to duplicate all the structures of the other structure. Is it possible to copy the fields of another structure? Perhaps using hypothetical syntax such as `#[derive(copy_fields_from  ="a::Product")]`.

Comment: Does the [newtype pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/features/types/newtype.html) not work for you?

Comment: no, because `async_graphql::InputObject ` adds functionality to the structure

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of doing this cleanly.

If you felt you *had* to do this, you'd need to write a build script that:

1. Located the source code of the target crate.
2. Parsed the source code using a crate like `syn`.
3. Located the types in question.
4. Output them again.

See also:

- [How do I apply a macro attribute to a function defined in a separate module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364002/155423)
- [Add Serialize attribute to type from third-party lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30793710/155423)
- [Is it possible for one struct to extend an existing struct, keeping all the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32552593/155423)

---

For your specific case, I'd advocate implementing whatever trait(s) by hand.